# How do I get a full path as an output in sl4a?

Tags: python-3.x, sl4a

Please refer to the following link first:

[File dialog in python sl4a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795626/file-dialog-in-python-sl4a)

If I modify the return statement to the following:

`return '{}'.format(target_path)`

And add the script to run the main function and modifying the function `show_dir(path=base_dir)` to `main(path=base_dir)` and call the main using the script below

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

The output shows of the dialog box shows what I want as output:

/sdcard/qpython/projects3/StudentIDCard/rva_student_data.xlsx,

However the console output shows only:

/sdcard

I am at a loss why the two outputs are different?

I need the full path information to the file as the output for further processing.

How do I get that?